# Coat interior brick work

Tags: brick

We have an interior brick wall that we want for seal to stop brick dust.

What is the best way to do this or what product do I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the look you want.  If you want to preserve the natural brick use a clear acrylic sealer. Or you can paint it the color of your choice.  Either way, you'll need to clean it well (and let it dry for a while) and follow product application instructions (paint may require a primer) - there are lots of product options available.  Acrylic sealer is a nice look.